# I can't connect to my mongo docker container by its name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm pretty new to docker but I'm having some issues getting a node app to connect to a mongo database running on a separate container.

I'm using the [official mongo image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)

I run it using:

```
docker run --name some-mongo --network-alias some-mongo -d mongo
```

It's running on port 27017 by default. I can connect to it using the mongo shell:

```
mongo --host mongodb://172.17.0.2:27017
```

But I can't connect to it by name

```
mongo --host mongodb://some-mongo:27017

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
connecting to: mongodb://some-mongo:27017/test
2018-05-07T17:23:20.813-0400 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("some-mongo") failed: Name or service not known
2018-05-07T17:23:20.813-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't initialize connection to host some-mongo, address is invalid :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:223:14
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Instead I get an error message about how I can't connect to the mongo host:

I'm trying some docker-compose tutorials but either they're too simple or they don't seem to work for me. I just want to connect a custom node app, (not the official node) to mongodb and some other dependencies.

Comment: You should put your app and mongo container into docker-compose.yml, and link them so they are visible to each other.

Comment: Good call! With an updated docker-compose file the aliases now work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is not altering your host's system configuration, so that the `mongo` service will not be available just like that. Agreeing with @unm4sk, you should compose you application's services into a single compose file like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
 mongo:
   image: mongo
   expose:
     - "27017"
   [...]
 service_utilizing_mongo:
   [...]
   links:
     - mongo:mongo
```

Then, your `service_utilizing_mongo` would have a DNS entry that'd make this service capable of accessing your `mongo` service via a alias `mongo` on a default `27017` port.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run your container with passing ports to your host machine:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --name some-mongo --network-alias some-mongo -d mongo
```

Then you can connect to **MongoDB** from your host machine:

If you don't want to do this you can connect to mongo through docker container command

```
docker exec -it some-mongo mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The problem was that I used networks only for mongo replicaset.
For solution just add this network to your application service.
Like this:
[image]